# Is there any way to label a grids rows and columns with numbers in Photoshop CC automatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, photoshop-scripting

So you draw your grid automatically (which I know how to do). Then I want it to number just the row and column automatically like so:

[image: just 1st row & col]

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would have thought from the example that it was obvious! I just wondered if there is a feature in photoshop somewhere that provides for the numbering of a grid as above - that is the first row is numbered 0 to n and the first column is also numbered 0 to n just to make it easier to reference a particular element in the 2D grid.

Comment: Can't do it without a custom script.